What is the equation that determine the crystal structure?
Is there a governing equation(s) that the crystal structure can be derived from?

Once translated into mathematics, algorithms can solve physical problems. An equation is a particular type of algorithm, although not all algorithms can be cast in the form of an equation.
Determining the crystalline structure is equivalent to the mathematical problem of finding the global minimum of a function depending on many variables (the potential energy for structures at zero temperature or the free energy at finite temperature).
Then, an algorithm for the crystalline structure depends on two main steps:

a sub-algorithm to evaluate energy or free energy reliably;
another algorithm to find the global minimum in such a potential energy landscape.

We know reliable algorithms can solve both steps in principle. However, practical reasons limit the complexity of the crystalline structures that can be obtained in a reasonable time because both steps have to be implemented by numerical computations.

A fun one I encountered some years ago was Ta2O5. As it turns out, the unit cell contains 77 atoms (11 formula units) of a mixture of octahedral and pentagonal bipyramidal arrangements of the oxygens around the tantalum, each a bit distorted from the others. Getting there through some algorithm without a lot of human intervention seems quite difficult.

@JonCuster It is difficult but not impossible with computational technology in the present day. The critical point is that algorithms exist, although their computational cost may rapidly exceed our present capabilities.

Unfortunately, it is hard to obtain "a sub-algorithm to evaluate energy or free energy reliably." Even at $T=0$ when you just want the ground state, you are not likely to get this right for a 77 atom unit cell "a priori." Even if you have some approximation method (e.g., DFT) that you can scale to work with a 77 atom unit cell, you will still have to have a very fine grid in a little tiny k-space cell, and you will get tons of horrible spaghetti band structure. Those bands that are far from the fermi level are probably not a good approximation to whatever is "really" down there.


Is there a governing equation(s) that the crystal structure can be derived from?

In principle the Schrodinger equation could tell you this, if only you could solve the Schrodinger equation. The problem is that crystals have lots of ions and electrons and it is impossible to solve the many-body Schrodinger equation exactly for more than two bodies...
In practice we have developed Density Functional Theory (DFT), which turns the intractable many-body problem into a more-tractable self-consistent single-body problem. Many of the problems are swept under a rug known as the exchange-correlation potential.
DFT usually treats only the electrons as dynamic and holds the ions fixed at the experimental crystal structure locations. But, DFT can also be used in Bohn-Oppenheimer Molecular Dynamics simulations that attempt to calculate the ion positions.
DFT practitioners (e.g., TDDFT, molecular dynamics, etc) might try to claim that they can figure out the crystal structure with their numerical calculations... but it only works "a priori" for certain simple systems and there are a bunch of hacks that usually have to be applied to reproduce the experimental crystal structure.

No, no, dft starts with importing the approximate crystalline structure measured from experiment. Can't start anything without that! (Ok, I know you meant only for certain simple systems we might get the crystalline structure to appear, but those people are really fringe.)

@naturallyInconsistent Not always. Some groups will claim that they can get stuff like the "correct" lattice spacing from DFT energy minimization (for various lattice spacings). And some will claim they can compare lattice structures and lattice spacings and "determine" the crystal structure.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0925838812022475

the "correct" lattice spacing is easily obtained from DFT. It is clearly an approximation, but it is not horrendous. Instead, I'm talking about the fact that, usually, you need to input the relative positions of the atoms keeping lattice parameter constant, and then let the DFT optimise the lattice parameter. Indeed, when we need to compute the phonon stuff, we often have to relax to the lattice parameter that DFT likes, as opposed to the physically measured lattice parameters. We know how much of it is nonsense, but it seems to give better agreement with experiment when we do that.

"We know how much of it is nonsense..." I don't think this is true. DFT is an unjustifiable approximation from the very beginning, and DFT-based molecular dynamics even moreso.

I think we are already in agreement. The technical term we prefer to use is "uncontrolled approximation". People who use it are aware that it is baloney. It just so happens that this particular kind of tarot reading is somewhat close to experiments and have a hint of physicality.

I think we agree too. :)
